# how to change the form style created using helper in play 2.1.0 with scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

i want to show form field horizontally . But when i use @helper.form , then they come vertically. how to change the design of the form in play 2.1.0

Comment: the correct tag is not play2-mini, but playframework.

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout ['Field constructors'](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaFormHelpers) to change the html layout of the form elements.

The form itself can be styled using regular CSS